# How do I configure a VPN in Lion?

Tags: macos, security, vpn

I've tried to configure VPN in Lion (both L2TP and PPTP), but it never connected successfully.

The same VPN works fine in Windows 7 and the iPad and other mobile devices, so I think it could be a problem with Lion.

Did I miss something when trying to configure the VPN?

My system is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (11C74).

---

Below is the log file.

L2TP:

```
12-1-12 下午10:18:56.705 configd: SCNC: start, triggered by System Preferen, type L2TP, status 0

12-1-12 下午10:18:56.744 pppd: pppd 2.4.2 (Apple version 560.13) started by stch, kid 501

12-1-12 下午10:18:56.746 pppd: L2TP connecting to server '106.187.38.10' (106.187.38.10)...

12-1-12 下午10:18:56.747 pppd: IPSec connection started

12-1-12 下午10:18:56.764 racoon: Connecting.

12-1-12 下午10:18:56.765 racoon: IPSec Phase1 started (Initiated by me).

12-1-12 下午10:18:56.765 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 1).

12-1-12 下午10:18:58.261 racoon: IKE Packet: receive success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 2).

12-1-12 下午10:18:58.268 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 3).

12-1-12 下午10:18:59.798 racoon: IKE Packet: receive success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 4).

12-1-12 下午10:18:59.824 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 5).

12-1-12 下午10:19:02.131 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).

12-1-12 下午10:19:05.589 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).

12-1-12 下午10:19:08.764 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).

12-1-12 下午10:19:09.732 racoon: Received retransmitted packet from
106.187.38.10[500].

12-1-12 下午10:19:20.870 racoon: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).

12-1-12 下午10:19:28.262 pppd: IPSec connection failed
```

pptp:

```
12-1-12 下午10:24:50.812 configd: SCNC: start, triggered by System Preferen, type PPTP, status 0

12-1-12 下午10:24:50.848 pppd: pppd 2.4.2 (Apple version 560.13) started by stch, kid 501

12-1-12 下午10:24:50.851 pppd: PPTP connecting to server '106.187.38.10' (106.187.38.10)...

12-1-12 下午10:24:54.425 pppd: PPTP connection established.

12-1-12 下午10:24:54.429 pppd: Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:17]

12-1-12 下午10:25:24.429 pppd: PPTP error when reading socket : EOF

12-1-12 下午10:25:24.429 pppd: PPTP error when reading header : read -1, expected 12 bytes

12-1-12 下午10:25:24.429 pppd: PPTP hangup

12-1-12 下午10:25:24.430 pppd: Connection terminated.

12-1-12 下午10:25:24.441 pppd: PPTP disconnecting...

12-1-12 下午10:25:24.441 pppd: PPTP disconnected
```

Comment: Have you checked the firewall on your Mac? Maybe it prevents the needed communication between the VPN device and your computer.

Comment: I regularly connect to multiple VPN's using Lion. I would make sure you have the authentication settings correct.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the firewall is not open and allow all connections in.  
I guess it might be line problem? I'm in china, using ADSL, using a wireless route and dial through PPPOE.  
Is it possible the ppp program on lion is not compatible with the PPPOE? or need I modify some configuration of the ppp prpgram?  
However, the vpn works fine on my win7 PC and ipad(using the same net topology), so it should not the vpn's provider's problem.

Comment: thanks for your answers!I input the wrong share password in l2tp, now I can connect vpn using l2tp.